# Can't find Edit Release option in new Google Play Console UI

Tags: apk, google-play-console

My app is live. I want to update my Apk. But I can't find the **Edit Release** option in New UI of Google Play Console.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I got the same issue. Do you find any way to Edit Release or any work-around?